# plot dataframe pandas not working

Tags: pandas

I am using pandas to plot a graph. The following is my function

```
count_subset.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

The response I get is

```
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x111fc4ad0>
```

I can't see the graph anywhere. Am I missing some library ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to 'show' the plot using matplotlib's `show`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...  #plotting code
plt.show()
```

Another way is, if you use IPython, to activate the matplotlib magic to have it interactively (no need to call show then):

```
%matplotlib
```